# Matplotlib Text artist - how to get size? (not using pyplot)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

### Background

I've moved some code to use **matplotlib only**, *instead of pyplot*  (The reason is it's generating png files in multi-process with futures, and pyplot isn't thread/process safe that way).

**So I'm creating my figure and axis via matplotlib.Figure(), not via pyplot.**

I've got some code that draw's a text 'table' on a figure, with one side right justified and the other left.  In order to keep the spacing between the two sides constant, I was previously using `get_window_extent()` on my left-side text artist to figure out the location of the right hand side:

```
     # draw left text at figure normalised coordinates, right justified
     txt1 = figure.text(x, y, left_str,         
                        ha='right', color=left_color, fontsize=fontsize)
     # get the bounding box of that text - this is in display coords
     bbox = txt1.get_window_extent(renderer=figure.canvas.get_renderer())

     # get x location for right hand side offset from left's bbox
     trans = figure.transFigure.inverted()      
     xr, _ = trans.transform((bbox.x1 + spacing, bbox.y0))

     # draw right side text, using lhs's y value
     figure.text(xr, y, right_str,
                 ha='left', color=right_color, fontsize=fontsize)
```

### Problem

My problem is now that I'm not using pyplot, the above code fails to work, because `figure.canvas.get_renderer()` fails to return a renderer, as I haven't set one, and am simply using Figure.savefig(path) to save my file when I'm done.

---

**So is there a way to find out the bounding box size of an Artist in a Figure without having a renderer set?**

---

From looking at legend, which allows you to use a bounding box line with variable text size, I'm presuming there is, but I can't find how.

I've had a look at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html, and also tried `matplotlib.artist.getp(txt1)` on the above, but didn't find any seemingly helpful properties.